# Can I change the properties of the Date type inside the get method?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a method that returns a collection of items

```
getDate() {
this.http.get(this.url, this.httpOptions)
.subscribe((res: any ) => {
  this.list = res.list;
  this.list.forEach(element => {
    return this.datePipe.transform(element.startTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  });  
});
}
```

I need to transform the date display. For this I want to use DatePipe. But can I do this within the method getDate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Observable.pipe()` function of Rxjs.

like so:

```
 this.http.get(this.url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
     map(val => val = this.datePipe.transform(val.startTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
  ).subscribe((res: any ) => {
    this.list = res.list;
  });
```

**edit**: your object seems to be a list so you could use `map()` to transform each element

Check out more here: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators

Comment: @trichetriche except the `.pipe(val => {` part.

Comment: That's even worse ! pipes require operators, not callback functions ...

Comment: but I can not call `element.startTime` inside of `this.datePipe.transform`

Comment: `val` has only base fields such as `constructor`, `valoeOf` ets. That is not yet my list

Comment: This is a list of elements as "someEvent", and each someEvent has fields `id`, `address`, `startTime`, `endTime` ets ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the scenario that you describe, if you can make a stackblitz I can try to help u further. (https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)

Comment: yes, I'm very grateful to you, but it still do not work

Comment: You need to create a stackblitz we can debug or show more code, we don't have enough information to help you right now @senjust

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
getDate() {
  this.http.get(this.url, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      map(res => res.list.map(element => ({
        ...element, 
        startTime: this.datePipe.transform(element.startTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
      )})))
     ).subscribe((res: any ) => {
       this.list = res.list;
     });  
}
```

Comment: ...`map(res => res.list.map(element`... In this row, I do not have access to the list yet

Comment: @senjust what do you mean, if you don't have access to the list in the pipe, you don't have access to the list in the subscribe.